# Java encode raw bytes into image simple image fomat/ file

Tags: java, image, scala, image-processing

I am very new to image encoding and would rather not learn a whole lot about it. Basically I'm taking greyscale byte array where each byte equals one pixel. I'm getting this data from mnist where I get 28x28 byte images. Anyway, bellow is my code, so you understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
  private def getImages = {
    val filePath = getClass.getResource("/mnist/train-images.idx3-ubyte").getPath
    val fis = new FileInputStream(filePath)
    var bytes = new Array[Byte](4)
    fis.read(bytes)
    println((ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt()))
    fis.read(bytes)
    println((ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt()))
    fis.read(bytes)
    var rows = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt()
    println("Number of rows: " + rows)
    fis.read(bytes)
    var cols = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt()
    println("Number of cols: " + cols)
    var imageBytes = new Array[Byte](rows * cols)
    fis.read(imageBytes)
    imageBytes.foreach(println(_))

    // I created a byte array input stream to feed into ImageIO
    // which should create my image
    val b = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes)

    // This is where your helpful answer would be placed
    // What is the code to encode this into jpeg, gif, or whatever?

    // This returns null because I have not encoded the bytes
    // in the proper format
    val img = ImageIO.read(b)

    // Errors out because img is null
    ImageIO.write(img, "gif", new File("/home/dev/woot.gif"))
  }
```

The format is just consecutive pixel bytes laid next to each other. My question is what Java library or function is available to convert these raw bytes into jpeg, gif, or whatever format I need?

Comment: Side note: Instead of using `InputStream` to read a 4 byte array, then wrapping it in a `ByteBuffer` to get an `int`, you could wrap `fis` in a `DataInputStream` and use its `readInt()` method. It's probably cleaner, but more importantly, it's safer. Note that `InputStream.read(byte[])` isn't guaranteed to fill the entire array, you *must* check the return value (unless there's Scala magic happening).

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I'm on and off with Java so I constantly forget things, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you write it out with `ImageIO`, create a `BufferedImage` first. It can be as simple as using the `setRGB` methods, and has the added benefit of allowing you to observe the image before writing it out.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I can use setRGB directly but your idea helped pointed me to setData() which takes in rasterized data. Thanks a bunch!